# Is react right approach for long list with dynamic data addition

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, reactjs, redux

I have to display a long list with 2000+ entries. the list data changes dynamically in a way that for each second at least one new row will be added. The approach I am using is with react redux is

```
render (){

   const listItems = this.state.listData.map((item, index) =>
     <li key={index}>
        <input value={item.name} /><input value={item.description}>
     </li>
   );
   return (
     <ul>{listItems}</ul>
   );
}
```

so whenever store data changes it will change the data in component state which will rerun the render method. now there will be list of items generated in the virtual dom. react will compare this with actual rendered dom and just updates the only the new changes in the dom.

This is fine for UI rendering engine but what about javascript engine. 
the problem I see is each time data changes the list of elements with 2000+ are recreated in javascript and compared to the dom snapshot. This is an unnecessary overloading considering javascript.

suppose if I am doing the same with javascript of jquery. it will be as simple as

```
socket.on('message', function(data){
  store.push(data);
  let listItem = $(`<li><input>${data.name}</input>
   <input>${data.description}</input></li>`);
   $('ul#main').append(listItem);
})
```

here a dom node is added on each time a message is received. this looks so simple with no overloading when compared to react way of doing. Is there is any better approach in react, redux that I fail to think. please let me know.

Comment: do you need to display all of them? You could paginate without making a server call

Comment: Hi  @AHBensiali,  This component has multiple usecases. In one of the usecases i have to display all the  messages. even if it is something like displaying 50-60 rows at a time there will be lot of javascript heavy loading since there is data addition every  second. so I am trying to find a better approach with react.

Comment: Are you seeing a problem with performance? You may be optimizing prematurely...

Answer (score 0):

You are choosing a poor key identifier. Please use an key identifier to identify your message (record id/title), this will eliminate the changes to the dom.

Comment: I am not talking about changes to dom but the work done by javascript. javascript iterating through 2000+ list items and create a virtual dom element and then comparing with dom. the below part is always executed since it is in render.
this.state.listData.map((item, index) =>
     <li key={index}>
        <input value={item.name} /><input value={item.description}>
     </li>
   );
 this happens on each second.

Comment: Yes, React uses an immutable state so you can't append to existing state but always need to recreate it. With much items special care should be taken with `shouldComponentUpdate`. The benefits you get from using immutable state and virtual dom diffing usually outweigh performance wins like you describe. Computers are powerful machines, usually poor programming leads to slow programs, React ensures components (and child components) get rendered only once when a state changes.

Comment: I agree to that but this seems like a framework limitation rather than programming ability. React addresses rendering issue but introduces heavy lifting to JS. Even though machines are powerful enough there should be a way to avoid unnecessary heavy loading. Assume there are 3-4 components like this on screen with live updates (may be a stock market website) and when you are viewing it on a mobile browser, then the performance will definitely go down. So there should be a way to optimize the code for this sort of need and that is what I am trying to think of.

Comment: Our job as a programmer is to write great code, optimizing is part of that but it's one of the last steps. So don't worry about it to much. Worry when it's an actual problem. Usually the bottlenecks aren't the loops, but unnecessary rerenders, because of lack of SCU. That said, good luck with your hunt :-)
Btw: I can't imagine a site with multiple component with thousands of rows in them, something is telling me that's a problem on itself.